# How to show the reference model in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm using Rails for backend and backbone.js as frond-end framework.

"Course" is the master table and "Video" is the reference table. Create course view(backboneJs view) is linked with "course" backbone model. In the same Create course view, I want to include the url values for video. How can i achieve that?

How to implement backbone model mapping? and How can i update the rails model when the backbone reference model gets update? Can someone explain with code?

Please advise.

```
            <!-- field where the video ID will be stored after the upload -->
            <input type="hidden" name="course.video[panda_video_id]"/>

            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name='course.video[title]' placeholder="Give a title">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.  The basic way is to create model that contains two collections; Course and Video.  Since Video is the child table, you would have to make sure the data is populated there first.  Inside your Course collection, you could add a method that will be called when a new record is inserted that will retrieve the video model from the Video collection and store it inside the Course model.  This method can be as simple as one that listens for changes to the video id change in the Course model and that way anytime you update this id, the method will run and reassign the video reference.  I'm assuming this will create a reference and not copy the object by value.

Here is a link to an already built solution if you would rather do that.

http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2013/02/tiny-model-relations-with-backbone-associate/

Comment: Hi Kalpers, Thanks, I'll check this tomorrow and let you know if it works.